# Signing using openssl with private key on HSM

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, hsm, opensc

I am using OpenSC/libp11 to access an HSM. I need to sign some data using private key generated and stored on the HSM. From libp11 I use the function:

`EVP_PKEY *PKCS11_get_private_key(PKCS11_KEY *key);`

to get a pointer to the EVP_PKEY structure representing the private key. Next I use the openssl functions:

```
 int EVP_DigestSignInit(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, EVP_PKEY_CTX **pctx,
                        const EVP_MD *type, ENGINE *e, EVP_PKEY *pkey);
 int EVP_DigestSignUpdate(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, const void *d, size_t cnt);
 int EVP_DigestSignFinal(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *sig, size_t *siglen);
```

to perform the signing operation. All these functions return successful and even the corresponding EVP_DigestVerifyInit/Update/Final functions return successul.

My question is that, in my case, is the signing operation actually being performed by/on the HSM as it is supposed to be? I have not loaded the openssl pkcs11 engine explicitly (passed NULL to the ENGINE* arg in EVP_DigestSignInit), I did not even add the engine path in my openssl conf. If the pkcs11 engine is not being used, then why do the sign/veriy functions return success?

Comment: Where the operation is performed depends on the provider (note: not the 'engine').  The OpenSC/libp11 is a shim between openssl syntax and p11 syntax, as implemented by the provider. The HSM vendor will be supplying the provider.  If it is implemented correctly, then yes -- the operation is performed on the HSM.  The get_private_key does not return the key itself, it returns a handle to the key.  The sign operations pass the handle along with the data back to the HSM, which accesses the actual key, signs the data, and returns the signature..Again: If implemented correctly.